# I am trying to create checkbox in pdf document using itextsharp and i am using to create pdf string builder append method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

sbnew12.Append("Permanent Address same as Present*YesNo");

I am trying like that to get checkbox but it was not getting

I am trying for a checkbox in pdf file and i am not getting i am using Itextsharp to create pdf and stringbuilder append method

Comment: Could you share your initial step you have tried so far? Or it would be great if you could share your scenario and relevant code snippet.

Comment: //  sbnew12.Append("<table><tr><td>Permanent Address same as Present*</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='address_same' value='Yes'>Yes</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='address_same' value='No'>No</td></tr></table>");

Comment: I am using Itextsharp library in .net core 5 using webapi